# How to set up a view that replaces a table once processed?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Every time I attempt to save a view that has "create or replace table" I get the error:Only SELECT statements are allowed in view queries.

I am using standard SQL in Google Cloud Big Query. I do not want the view as a scheduled query and the view is too large to run, meaning it errors out asking for me to create a table that allows large results. I want the query to update its associated table every time it is run. I came across the Write_Truncate syntax, however I do not know to use it.

create or replace `table.test1` as( all my other queries)

I just expect for big query to allow me to run the table.

Comment: How about setting up a job or scheduled query to save the results into a specific table?  Then just query that.

Comment: How big is your underlying table?  I have several views on a table with 10s of TBs of session data.